# Cannot edit file via group permission

Tags: permissions, filesystem, groups, acl

there's a system with two users: `codera` and `coderb`.
They both belong to group named `firma`.
However, when one of them creates a file (in `/tmp`) and changes it's group ownership
to `firma`, with `rw` group permission, the other still cannot write that file...
Below is the story in terminal:

```
codera@vbox:/tmp$ touch file_a
codera@vbox:/tmp$ chown codera:firma file_a
codera@vbox:/tmp$ ls -al file_a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 codera firma 0 úno 14 20:12 file_a
```

So, if how I understand it, both the file owner (`codera`) and members of the group `firma` *should* be able to read/write that file. Let's try it in second terminal window:

```
pb@vbox:~$ sudo su - coderb # (then password typed)
coderb@vbox:~$ cd /tmp
coderb@vbox:/tmp$ ls -al file_a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 codera firma 0 úno 14 20:12 file_a
coderb@vbox:/tmp$ id # lets check groups one more time
uid=1002(coderb) gid=1002(coderb) groups=1002(coderb),27(sudo),1005(firma),1006(cpp)
coderb@vbox:/tmp$ echo hello > file_a
-bash: file_a: Permission denied
```

According to `man acl`, after checking whether the user (resp. process) is an owner, if the effective GID **or** any of the supplementary group IDs match the file group, then those *rw-* permissions should be applied.

I tried `newgrp - firma` too... It changed the gid succesfully, but did not help accessing the file. Neither helped rebooting the machine (way to force logout/login them all), or logging in graphically as `coderb`.

Could anybody explain me what did I do wrong or what I missed, please?

Below is info about the OS. It runs in VirtualBox:

```
coderb@vbox:/tmp$ uname --all
Linux vbox 5.8.0-41-generic #46~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 17:52:23 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thank you all for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do:

```
$ ls -lad /tmp
drwxrwxrwt 28 root root 36864 Feb 14 22:26 /tmp
```

You'll see that it has the [sticky bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit) (`t`) set. This prevents users from removing or renaming files of other users. Recent Linux also takes this further by introducing [the `fs.protected_regular` sysctl](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/fs.txt) which also prevents writing to other users' files in such directories.

You could do what you want to do in a directory that isn't set sticky or if it's just writes you could disable that sysctl (system-wide).

Comment: Thank you, this works. I'm confused by that however - according to `man chmod`, sticky bit should only prevent users from renaming or deletion of files, I can't see there anything about preventing them writing/editing

Comment: It's a Linux extension based on the sysctl ```fs.protected_regular``` and its interaction with sticky directories. I'll update the answer to include this info. https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/fs.txt